# var_export結果を、arrayではなく[]で表示する方法はありますか？

Tags: php

var_export結果を、arrayではなく[]で表示する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ライブラリやフレームワークなしで、標準の方法となるとないと思います。
本家に同様の質問がありましたのでリンクを。Symfonyなんかは抱えているようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316347/how-to-format-var-export-to-php5-4-array-syntax

私の場合、単に短く表示したい場合は、json_encodeをよくつかいます。